# When does a closure in Python finish execution or go out of scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

I am trying to wrap my brain around closures. I’ve been looking at a lot of sources, but this question is based mainly on the explanation in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

I think I get the idea of a callback as a closure, to handle events that happen after something in the outer function has happened / been called. I guess that’s what happening with deferreds in Scrapy.
I’ve also seen examples in Python using the logging module.

Ok, but, *but*, you can’t call a closure on its own, right? Because that would be calling it outside the scope of where it was defined. Putting it another way, you can’t call a closure directly, you have to call the enclosing function which returns it. But if that’s the case, then the use case for closures is limited by its dependency on the outer function. The fact that it remembers the free variables of the enclosing environment after the outer function has ceased execution does not make the closure a little portable unit you can take and use anywhere and it will work without the outer function, right?

But if that’s right, then how can this also be right:

> “...When the closure is entered at a later time, possibly with a
>   different lexical environment, the function is executed with its
>   non-local variables referring to the ones captured by the closure, not
>   the current environment…” Wikipedia - same link - #(“Implementation and theory”)

**This is why I am struggling so hard with closures.** The idea that they remember values post execution sounds, at least to me, like it has a life independent of the enclosing function, as though you can call it or use it in “a different lexical environment”. But that’s not true if the enclosing function is right there with it, is it?

This example from [datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python#closures) helps spell out what I find confusing in a simpler example:

> In Python, a function is also considered a object, which means that it
>   can be returned and assigned to a variable. In the next example,
>   you'll see that instead of inner() being called inside outer(), return
>   inner is used. Then, outer() is called with a string argument and
>   assigned to closure. Now, even though the functions inner() and
>   outer() have finished executing, their message is still preserved. By
>   calling closure(), the message can be printed.

```
def outer(message):
    # enclosing function
    def inner():
        # nested function
        print(message)
    return inner


closure = outer("Hello world!")
closure()
Hello world!
```

> Notice that if you call closure without parentheses, only the type of 
>   the object will be returned. You can see that it's of the type function

```
__main__.outer.<locals>.inner.closure

<function __main__.outer.<locals>.inner>
```

> Now, even though the functions inner() and outer() have finished
>   executing, their message is still preserved.

In what sense have either inner() or outer() “finished executing” in this example? They haven’t even been *called* until you call closure()!
What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: `outer` was called here: `outer("Hello world!")` and is finished executing by the time you get to the next line, `closure()`, and note, `closure` **is** `inner`. So it is called, obviously, when `closure` is called. Also, not sure what you mean by "you can't call a closure on it's own", but I don't think that's right.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : What I meant was, you can't just call inner(), because you will get a NameError. Maybe I am being too technical here, but I can see what you mean that closure "is" inner, because it is the return value of outer.

Comment: No, it *literally is the function being created by the function definition `def inner`*. You can't call `inner()` because *the name is out of scope* and doesn't refer to anything in the global scope. Think of it this way, a function definition is just syntactic sugar for instatiating a `Function` object, something othe effect of `Function(code, free_variables)`. So, `inner = Function(<code-object>, <mapping of free variables>)` and then `return inner`.

Comment: Indeed, you can get `Function = type(lambda x:x)` and get the function class, and indeed, while it's arguments are quite complex and not well documented, you can use it to create a function object that will behave exactly like one you created using `def` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They haven’t even been called until you call closure()!

Actually, the statement `closure = outer("Hello world!")` calls the `outer()` function with the argument `"Hello world!"`. At that time, the `outer()` function executes, thereby defining the `inner()` function and returning the function `inner` itself, assigning the function to the variable `closure`. **At this point, outer() has "finished executing".**

Next, by calling `closure()`, the function `inner()` is actually invoked, returning the preserved message.

Comment: Really? That's an execution, and not just an assignment?

Comment: @MalikA.Rumi, yes, using `()` after a function, with our without arguments, executes the function. Leaving the `()` off is just referring to the function without executing.

Comment: Ok, well, all three of you have taught me something today, but I'm giving you the points for the most succinct answer. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2):

The description is poorly worded; the function `inner` wasn't executed during the call to `outer`, just the `def` statement that *defines* it.

Among other attributes, the `function` object defined by `def inner(): ...` has one named `_closure__` that contains the value to use when the nonlocal name `message` is looked up.

```
>>> closure.__closure__[0].cell_contents
'Hello'
```

To the best of my understanding (which is not, admittedly, great), each nonlocal variable in the definition of `inner` is numbered, and a tuple containing one `cell` object per nonlocal name is stored in `__closure__`. Each `cell` has an attribute `cell_contents` which contains the value held by the nonlocal name when `outer` returns.